# UIWebView begins loading but never finishes

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

My UIWebView begins loading a webpage but never finishes leaving me with a white page. My code below

```
import UIKit

class WebsiteController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {
    var index: Int = Int();
    var postLink: String = String()

    @IBOutlet weak var Browser: UIWebView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        let school = (defaults.objectForKey("School") as! String)
        let bundleidentifier = NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleIdentifier
        var links: [String] = [String]()
        if let aStreamReader = StreamReader(path: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(school, ofType: "txt")!)
        {
            defer {
                aStreamReader.close()
            }
            while let line = aStreamReader.nextLine() {
                links.append(line)
            }
        }
        let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: links[index].stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLPathAllowedCharacterSet())!)!
        let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
        Browser.loadRequest(request)
        Browser.delegate = self
        Browser.opaque = false
        Browser.backgroundColor = UIColor .clearColor()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    func webViewDidStartLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
        print("starting")
    }
    func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
        print("finishing")
    }
```

So In console when i load this view i get"starting" but never "finishing"

Answer (score 0):

Check for error in `didFailLoadWithError` method.

Comment: Yes i did get an error  with that, a requested URL not found the server error here is part of the error log.

Comment: starting
failed
Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1100 "The requested URL was not found on this server." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x13712b350 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1100 "The requested URL was not found on this server." UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=file://http%3a//www.oncoursesystems.com/school/webpage/12781583/1265131%0D, NSLocalizedDescription=The requested URL was not found on this server., NSErrorFailingURLKey=file://http%3a//www.oncoursesystems.com/school/webpage/12781583/1265131%0D}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey

Comment: Well your url does not exist on the server.. and server returns error... check url...

Comment: I have checked the url and it works. I think the error is coming from how I am converting the String url to a NSURL, can you check that?

Comment: add `print("\(url)")` and see what it says in console

Comment: Its not correctly translating the url. Its putting in %3 in place of : and its adding a %0D at the end(perhaps in place of a space?). What Character set should i use to prevent this from happening

Comment: That part is fine, why do you have `file://` before `http....` from where are you reading that url, add `print("'\(line)")` and see what it says...

Comment: I am getting this url from a txt file with a link on every line. and what is the line variable you are referring to in the print command

Answer (score 0):

Check your console to see if you get an App Transport Security error. I was having the same problem. The url was correct and working web-side and `webViewDidStartLoad(:_)` was being hit but `webViewDidFinishLoad(:_)` was never hit. After printing out the url to console, I noticed this error `App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.`